# Need help replacing a special tag with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to build a parser for my c# program.

I want simulate php style short tags

I'm using JScript as the parser.

my tags are `<?js` and `?>`

### I need a regex replace from my in/out code blocks :(

IN

```
<?js
test();
function test()
{
   print("text to print");
   ?>text to print<?js
}
?>
```

out

```
    test();
    function test()
    {
       print("text to print");
       print("text to print");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\<\?js([\s\S]*?)\?\>
```

You can use the regex expression of the above to replace `"<?js>"` and `"?>"` that get the right result, but you need add the special print statement by manual operation.